# Python Tkinter Label Refresh Woes

Tags: python, tkinter, label, refresh, bitcoin

Im back again with another python issue.
A short while ago I wrote a console based program that pulls stats from a bitcoin miner on your local network. I've decided I'd like to turn it into a gui, and choose a combination of EasyGUI and Tkinter for my program.

My input boxes (ip, refresh rate,asic type) are all using EasyGUI, simply to save lines of code as Tkinter would take far more writing to accomplish the same. However, My actual results page is written using Tkinter as it allows me to refresh the displayed data at a user-defined interval.

My issue is this:
I had my program running happily, and then made some small ui tweaks (title, font, etc) and now after my most recent compile (using pyinstaller) I've noticed the stats (labels) don't update at all. I have looked over my code countless times now and cannot seem to find what is blocking the stats from changing at the defined intervals.

I am hoping someone with a fresh pair of eyes can help me find my stupid mistake, as it was running perfectly before these small additions.

Heres a cut-down version that still runs and produces the same issue:

```
import Tkinter as tk

from pycgminer import CgminerAPI

cgminer = CgminerAPI()
cgminer.host = 192.168.x.x
summary = cgminer.summary()
update = 1000
def L1(label):
    def hashrate():
        msg = "Your current GH/S = "
        speed = msg , summary['SUMMARY'][0]['GHS 5s']
        label.config(text=speed)
        label.after(update, hashrate)
    hashrate()
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Eyes On Miner GUI V0.2")
label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()
L1(label)
root.mainloop()
```

Full code on pastebin, in case you'd like to try to run it yourself. (python 2.7) [Full Code](http://pastebin.com/p7Yx70Bx)

Comment: Please read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. You can probably edit that code down to about 10% of it's size and still illustrate the problem you're having.

Comment: no, links to another site are frowned upon. If you removed or modified that code in the future it would break the question.

Comment: It's okay to include the link.  Just include enough code here that it isn't needed.

Comment: I suspect that you can shorten further and still see the problem.  Can you eliminate the non-tkinter imports?

Comment: Now CgminerAPI is a NameError ;-).  The only thing relevant to the label is `summary['SUMMARY'][0]['GHS 5s']`.  What type is the result?  Can you give me an example value? If you do, I will plug it in and try the further reduced code.

Comment: Had to re-add the pycgminer import, or it isnt runnable to test... however I have spaced it away from the tkinter for easier viewing. An example value from my label is 497.86 and it is a float int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran this much of your code, substituting `time()` for the summary.  It works in IDLE.  From the console, either run with `python -i program.py` or add `root.mainloop`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import time

update = 1000
def L1(label):
    def hashrate():
        msg = "Your current GH/S = "
        speed = msg , time()
        label.config(text=speed)
        label.after(update, hashrate)
    hashrate()
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Eyes On Miner GUI V0.2")
label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()
L1(label)
```

If the problem is not with `summary['SUMMARY'][0]['GHS 5s']`, then there must be an incompatibility with either `CgminerAPI` or more likely with `easygui`.  The latter is meant to replace tkinter, not be used together with it.  If the code worked at first and then quit, then one of the additional functions you used must have triggered a conflict.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help, the issue must be with the combo of PyCgminer and Tkinter, because I have completely removed the EasyGui code and the issue still persists, I'll have to find a work around for the PyCgminer module, or simply write my own version within the code.